# Nth Occurrence in Date Order based on two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to lookup the date for the nth [e.g. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, Last] business day for a given month and currency.

e.g. the [1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, Last] "Business Day" for "PLN" in the month of January.

(The below dates may be wrong - here is the sample data)

| DATE | CURRENCY | DAY TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | PLN | New Years Day |
| 1/2/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/3/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/4/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/5/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/6/2022 | PLN | Epiphany |
| 1/7/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/8/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/9/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/10/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/11/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/12/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/13/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/14/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/15/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/16/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/17/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/18/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/19/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/20/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/21/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/22/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/23/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/24/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/25/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/26/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/27/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/28/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 1/29/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/30/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 1/31/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 2/1/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 2/2/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 2/3/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 2/4/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 2/5/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 2/6/2022 | PLN | Weekend |
| 2/7/2022 | PLN | Business Day |
| 2/8/2022 | PLN | Business Day |

My attempt at creating a function to complete this:

```
Function NthBusinessDay(Nth As Variant, FcstCurrency As Variant, MonthNumber As Variant, YearNumber As Variant) As Variant
Dim varVal1 As Variant
Dim varVal2 As Variant
Dim varVal3 As Variant
Dim varVal4 As Variant
Dim rngTargetA As Range
Dim rngTargetB As Range
Dim lngRowCounter As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

varVal1 = FcstCurrency
varVal2 = MonthNumber
varVal3 = YearNumber
varVal4 = Nth

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("CCY_HOL_CAL(LIVE)")
lngRowCounter = 2
Set rngTargetA = ws.Range("B" & lngRowCounter)
Set rngTargetB = ws.Range("C" & lngRowCounter)
Do While Not IsEmpty(rngTargetA.Value)
    If rngTargetA.Value = varVal1 And rngTargetB.Value = "Business Day" Then
        FindValue = ws.Range("A" & lngRowCounter).Value
        Exit Function
    End If

    lngRowCounter = lngRowCounter + 1
    Set rngTargetA = ws.Range("B" & lngRowCounter)
    Set rngTargetB = ws.Range("C" & lngRowCounter)
Loop

FindValue = "Nothing"

End Function
```

How do I make this function hold true for the nth day and the last day in a given month?

Expected results: 
1st Business Day = 1/3/2022
2nd Business Day = 1/4/2022
3rd Business Day = 1/5/2022
4th Business Day = 1/7/2022
Last Business Day = 1/31/2022

Comment: Don't you want extracting the business days from the first column? Should the function be based on the corresponding 'qualification' of column "DAY TYPE". And which influence to have "PLN" in the above question, since you mentioned: **"Business Day" for "PLN" in the month of January**?

Comment: @FaneDuru The above code should find the date value in "A", Yes Day Type should qualify the relevant business days, The dataset has different currencies in column B not pictured for the sake of keeping this short enough.

Comment: What is `Nth As Variant`, since it is not used at all in your function? The number of first business days to be returned?

Comment: Yes should be the nth business day e.g. 1/2/3/4 or last within a month

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer. It will use arrays and should be very fast even for large ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next function. It firstly creates an array of date respecting the function parameters conditions (business days for parameters in discussion), then extract first `Nth` days and the last one, in an array. The `Nth` days are placed in their own array, and last one as `Date`, in the returned array second element:

```
Function NthBusinessDay(Nth As Long, FcstCurrency As String, MonthNumber As Long, YearNumber As Long) As Variant
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, k As Long, lastD As Date
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR).Value
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr)): k = 1
  'build an array of dates mathing the function requirements:
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        'Debug.Print Month(arr(i, 1)), Year(arr(i, 1)): Stop
        If arr(i, 2) = FcstCurrency And Month(arr(i, 1)) = MonthNumber And _
                   Year(arr(i, 1)) = YearNumber And arr(i, 3) = "Business Day" Then
            arrFin(k) = arr(i, 1): k = k + 1
        End If
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To k - 1)

  'Prepare the data to be returned
  Dim arrFrst: ReDim arrFrst(1 To Nth): k = 1
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrFrst)
     arrFrst(k) = arrFin(i): k = k + 1
  Next

  'return in an array:
  NthBusinessDay = Array(arrFrst, arrFin(UBound(arrFin)))
End Function
```

The above function should be called in the next way:

```
Sub testNthbusinessDay()
   Dim arrRet, i As Long, strBD As String
   arrRet = NthBusinessDay(4, "PLN", 1, 2022)
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrRet(0))
        strBD = strBD & "Business Day " & i & " = " & arrRet(0)(i) & vbLf
   Next i
   strBD = strBD & "Last Business Day = " & arrRet(1)
   MsgBox strBD
End Sub
```